# Rails bootstrap dropdown does not work on subsequent pages when javascript tag is placed in body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

When in responsive mode, bootstrap dropdown works on intial page visit/refresh but when another page is visited (via the dropdown link or any page link) it drops down but doesn't go back up. This happens when the `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` is placed at the bottom of the body tag. Everything works fine when the javascript tag is moved to the head but this is not best practice as regards js files and DOM load. My bootstrap files are added manually and not with a gem. Why is this happening this way? Is there something I am missing?

Here is my application.js file arrangement

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require turbolinks
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of turbolinks.

Try "data-no-turbolink"

```
%ul.dropdown-menu{:role => 'menu', :'aria-labeledby' => "something", "data-no-turbolink" => true}
```